# https requests with axios not made in deployment mode in REACT

Tags: reactjs, axios, httprequest, web-deployment, github-pages

I'm fetching a json file using axios in my react project. The rquest is made and I get a response on my localhost. However, on github pages when I deploy, the request is not made.
I double checked using the networks tab in chrome devtools.

My code

[image]

the url I'm requesting: [here](https://scaleflex.cloudimg.io/v7/0.fe_task_static/pictures.json?vh=7a646d&func=proxy)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: When i open the network tab in devtools and filter requests by choosing only FETCH/XHR, on local host I find a request sent with it's headers and resonse displayed on the right. However, notihing show when I open the same tab in deployment and the images I try to fetch doesn't render.

Comment: Can you please check in the console tab, have you got any error related cors?

Comment: @YugmaPatel I've doubled checked this. There was no CORS errors. The answer below solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the request when your component unmounts (cleanup function) instead on its mount. Instead of returning a function in useEffect you should do the request directly.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://scaleflex.cloudimg.io/v7/0.fe_task_static/pictures.json?vh=7a646d&func=proxy').then((res) => {
    setImages(res.data);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for 3 hours.